# Replacement Soldering Iron Tip

Tags: soldering, identification

I'm trying to replace the tip on my soldering iron. I got it a few years ago and quickly destroyed the tip. The problem is the iron is generic, and I cannot find any markings to identify the correct tip size. Here are a photo and some measurements.

[image]

They look alot like [this set](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07BT1WLRN), but appear to be too short.

Here is a photo of the station:

[image]

Here is a more detailed photo of the pen. The hollow shaft goes through the entire tip.

[image]

Comment: What soldering iron do you have? That's pretty important

Comment: AFAIK it's a Velleman/Nippon tip. Check this
https://www.ebay.com/itm/5-Pack-2-5-Replacement-Tips-Heads-for-Adjustable-Soldering-Station-79B100SS-/263001978596

Comment: I am attaching additional photos.

Comment: @Archimedes I think you are correct. Those look identical, the length matches, and the compatible stations look exactly like mine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Archimedes You should write that as an answer so this question can be marked answered!

Comment: @KevinReid ok, I thought it's too short for an answer...

Comment: @Archimedes It's good for answers to be detailed, but it's much more important that answers are posted as answers so they can be voted on and accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's a Velleman VTSS5 or Nippon 79B100SS soldering stations tip. You can get one [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/5-Pack-2-5-Replacement-Tips-Heads-for-Adjustable-Soldering-Station-79B100SS-/263001978596).